# What is the safe number of Threads to be initialised in Windows Phone

Tags: multithreading, performance, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am aware that Windows Phone devices are diverse in hardware, especially CPU resources.
But, by practical experience, does anybody know about that **number of Threads that can be run simultaneously** so as to prevent device performance issues and battery consumption.
By threads, i mean, the ones initialized by `Thread` class, using `.Start()` method.

Comment: That entirely depends on what they're doing.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks! This itself seems to be generalized answer :)

Comment: You should use the thread pool... without knowing your problem this should be the best solution as it might have the best size for WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of thread safely possible in WP depends on the amount of resources consumed and work done by the Threads. The more the resources / work done by threads, more will be load on CPU.
Try using Thread Pool for better performance.

Hope it satisfies your query :)